# Substutuir ")" por espaço usando str_replace_all() no R

Tags: string, r

Tenho o seguinte `data.frame`:

```
cadastros <- data.frame(
  email = c('joaodasilva@gmail.com', 'rafael@hotmail.com', 'maria@uol.com.br', 'juliana.morais@outlook.com'),
  telefone = c('(61)99831-9482', '32 8976 2913', '62-9661-1234', '15-40192.5812')
)
```

Preciso substituir todos os ")" e "(" por espaços em branco. Tentei tudo que que é possível e imaginável. Vou colocar a seguir cada uma das tentativas com os respectivos erros:

**Primeira tentativa**

```
  > library(stringr)
    > str_replace_all(string = cadastros,
    +                 pattern = ")",
    +                 replacement = "[[:blank:]]")
    Error in stri_replace_all_regex(string, pattern, fix_replacement(replacement),  : 
      Incorrectly nested parentheses in regexp pattern. (U_REGEX_MISMATCHED_PAREN)
    In addition: Warning message:
    In stri_replace_all_regex(string, pattern, fix_replacement(replacement),  :
      argument is not an atomic vector; coercingstr_replace(cadastros, 'c', " ")
```

**Segunda tentativa**

```
> cadastros2<-cadastros%>%
> +     str_replace_all(cadastros,"6", replacement = "[[:blank:]]") Error in str_replace_all(., cadastros, "6", replacement =
> "[[:blank:]]") :    unused argument ("6")
```

**Terceira tentativa**

```
> str_replace_all(cadastros, pattern = ")",replacement = "[[:blank:]]")
Error in stri_replace_all_regex(string, pattern, fix_replacement(replacement),  : 
  Incorrectly nested parentheses in regexp pattern. (U_REGEX_MISMATCHED_PAREN)
In addition: Warning message:
In stri_replace_all_regex(string, pattern, fix_replacement(replacement),  :
  argument is not an atomic vector; coercing
```

**Quarta tentativa**

```
> str_replace_all(cadastros, pattern = ")","[[:blank:]]")
Error in stri_replace_all_regex(string, pattern, fix_replacement(replacement),  : 
  Incorrectly nested parentheses in regexp pattern. (U_REGEX_MISMATCHED_PAREN)
In addition: Warning message:
In stri_replace_all_regex(string, pattern, fix_replacement(replacement),  :
  argument is not an atomic vector; coercing
```

Qualquer ajuda é bem vinda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em `stringr` você precisa inserir `[]` dentro das funções para que o caractere seja reconhecido. Ficaria assim para a variável `telefone`:

```
library(stringr)

str_replace_all(cadastros$telefone,'[()]',' ') # o último argumento é o espaço a ser inserido: ' '

#[1] " 61 99831-9482" "32 8976 2913"   "62-9661-1234"   "15-40192.5812"
```

Para aplicar esta função a todas as variáves (como você tentou), faça:

```
library(magrittr)

cadastros %>%
    sapply(function(x){
        str_replace_all(x,'[()]',' ')
    })

    # email                        telefone        
#[1,] "joaodasilva@gmail.com"      " 61 99831-9482"
#[2,] "rafael@hotmail.com"         "32 8976 2913"  
#[3,] "maria@uol.com.br"           "62-9661-1234"  
#[4,] "juliana.morais@outlook.com" "15-40192.5812"
```

Answer (score 4):

Você pode usar a função `gsub()`:

```
gsub("\\(|\\)", " ", cadastros$telefone)
# [1] " 61 99831-9482" "32 8976 2913"   "62-9661-1234"   "15-40192.5812"
```

O primeiro argumento você fornece a padrão que quer substituir e o segundo será o substituto. Repare que utilisei `|` para fornecer dois padrões ao mesmo tempo. Isso evita escrever a função para cada parêntesis:
    gsub("\(", " ", cadastros$telefone)
    gsub("\)", " ", cadastros$telefone)

Para manter um padrão coerente com todos os números que você forneceu no exemplo, eu faria assim:

```
cadastros$telefone <- gsub("\\(", "", cadastros$telefone)
cadastros$telefone <- gsub("\\)|\\-|\\.", " ", cadastros$telefone)

cadastros
# email      telefone
# 1      joaodasilva@gmail.com 61 99831 9482
# 2         rafael@hotmail.com  32 8976 2913
# 3           maria@uol.com.br  62 9661 1234
# 4 juliana.morais@outlook.com 15 40192 5812
```